# My 1:30 minute long WAV file is only playing for three seconds

Tags: java

I'm trying to play a .wav file in this code, but for some reason it only plays the minute-long song for about three seconds. Does anyone have any ideas why?

```
private void btnPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

   try {
        JFXPanel j = new JFXPanel();
        String uri = new File("04_Kensington_Chump (1).wav").toURI().toString();
        new MediaPlayer(new Media(uri)).play();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new media player in the method, and just leaving it there without storing it in a variable you can later access. This causes the garbage collector to pick it up.

Create a list to store all your media players so the garbage collector doesn't destroy them, and that should fix the problem

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(uri));
player.play();
someList.add(player);
```

Then periodically clean the list when players are done playing the audio